# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR; MEAN stack, Nginx

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, ssl, deployment

I have been having problems and I appreciate some help.
I have an application made with Angular and Node which was working well, but I installed SSL on it and I got some issues, the client seems to have no problems but when it try to do a request with the back-end I get an error like this 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR;'. The distribution of my project on the server is as follows:
Inside the 'Project' folder I have the following>> app.js  controllers  index.js  node_modules   package.json  uploads client  global.js  models  package-lock.json  routes

In the 'client' folder, there is the angular 'dist' in which I have not configured anything regarding HTTPS, the only thing that I have changed is the global variable with the route to the API, in this case it goes from having http to https.

Then I will leave the configurations of the backend and the nginx server.
Thank you very much.

```
#so far this is how my nginx setup looks like, 
#I have tried to add a location to the api 
#but I have not been able to solve the issue.

`server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name alejandroalonzo.com www.alejandroalonzo.com;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name alejandroalonzo.com www.alejandroalonzo.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/alejandroalonzo_com_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    location / {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:3700;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /api {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:3700/api;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


    error_page 497 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;
}
```

```
//On the other hand, this is how my configuration looks like in the backend.

//INDEX.JS



`"use strict";

//const https = require('https');
//const fs = require('fs');

//const options = {
//  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/ssl/server.key'),
//  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/ssl/alejandroalonzo_com_chain.crt')
//};


var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var app = require("./app");
var port = 3700;

//const server = https.createServer(options, app);

//mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/portfolio", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("database conexion ok..");
    app.listen(port, function () {
      console.log("server is running... Url->127.0.0.1:3700");
    });
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));


//APP.JS
"use strict";
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var path = require("path");

var app = express();
var project_routes = require("./routes/project");

//midlewares
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Cors
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method"
  );
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
  res.header("Allow", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
  next();
});

app.use("/", express.static("client", { redirect: false }));
app.use("/api", project_routes);

app.get("*", function (req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve("client/index.html"));
});

module.exports = app;
`
```

Comment: *"but when it try to do a request with the back-end"* - and what exactly does this request look like? And who produces the requests and gets the error?